# java not logging message after fix for log 2.15.0

Tags: java

i update to log 2.15.0 https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228

```
    <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
```

but after this update i don't get log no more

i get now spring.log.0 which is xml data

i not change my application-properties

if i remove this line in pom.xml

```
    <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
```

all is working again normal

i have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

gracias

Comment: Did you have a log4j dependency before?

Comment: Sounds like a Spring Boot application that did not have log4j2 before. Check your dependency tree without the line, or look at the logging configuration file you have in your project - is it logback.* or log4j2.*? Spring Boot defaults to logback. If you actually *were* using log4j2 before, you need to provide more information, we've all upgraded and or logging is fine.

Comment: yes i have spring-boot-starter-log4j2

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.6.1 only supports `log4j-core:2.14.1` and `log4j-api:2.14.1` - have you tried to force version `2.15.0` for both JARs? I am not familiar with Maven, but have tried this with Gradle and was able to see logs.

Comment: i work with maven and that is what i put in question

Comment: for the specific version, you can use `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.15.0</version>
  </dependency>`

to exclude, 
`<!-- For CVE-2021-44228 -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>`

please let me know if that works.

Comment: You've done it correctly, see e.g. https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot. I'll try to reproduce your setup.  Can you e.g. share your log4j2.xml file?

Comment: I did the version property update in my projects without any issues. You should share your log4j2 configuration because it's supposed to work out-of-the-box. Maybe clean your project and recompile everything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.